# Is it possible to load new PostgreSQL libraries without restarting the server?

Tags: postgresql, uuid

I need support for the `uuid` library in my Postgres server (a 64-bit Amazon Linux AMI). I've installed the `uuid` and `uuid-pgsql` packages. Is it possible to load the library without restarting the Postgres server?

PostgreSQL version is 8.4.11.

Comment: Have you read and followed the instructions in [the PostgreSQL manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createextension.html)?

Comment: @voretaq7 actually I'm on 8.4, so I don't think I have CREATE EXTENSION. This is the closest I've found, but suggest I have to restart the server anyway: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564056/how-do-i-import-modules-or-install-extensions-in-postgres-8-4

Comment: Indeed, `CREATE EXTENSION` is a 9.x (I believe 9.0) feature. (You should probably include your Postgres version in your question - absent any version-specific clues folks generally tend to assume "the latest stable release" :-)

Answer (score 0):

On 8.4.x you should be able to activate the extension once installed by simply loading the SQL file that came with it (the extensions are basically collections of C functions and other goodies - Postgres loads that stuff dynamically).  [The stack overflow question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564056/how-do-i-import-modules-or-install-extensions-in-postgres-8-4) talks about how to go about this (it's discussed in the manual [waaaaay in the back in Appendix F - "Additional Supplied Modules"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/contrib.html)

On **9.1** (I had the wrong version in my comment) and later this functionality has been subsumed by the [`CREATE EXTENSION`/`ALTER EXTENSION` SQL commands](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createextension.html) -- Module installation is essentially the same, only instead of having to load the SQL file manually the necessary changes are handled for you by Postgres when you run `CREATE EXTENSION`.